# How to fire only one .gesture when there is shift pressed

Tags: swiftui

I have a view that will have two kinds of tap gestrures attached to it.
Something like

```
view
.gesture(TapGesture().onEnded {...}) // <-- Don't fire this when shift is pressed
.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().modifiers(.shift).onEnded {....})
```

How I prevent the first gesture to be fired when shift is pressed.
Under all circumstances I want only one gesture to be fired.

applying both gestures on view like .gesture does not work
The second one is not fired at all, under any circumstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make second one with higher priority, like

```
view
.gesture(TapGesture().onEnded {...})
.highPriorityGesture(TapGesture().modifiers(.shift).onEnded {....})
```